# Node-Salesforce: What are possible options for execute function?

Tags: node.js, api, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I can't find the documentation for the 'options' object in node-salesforce library. Any help would be tremendously appreciated

I'm using node-salesforce library with the execute function where I pass the 'options' parameter. I would like to get all the data for Analytics-Report. Currently, I'm getting partial data in the response

```
report.execute(optionObjectGoesHere, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by partial data? The Salesforce Reports and Dashboards API has inherent limitations on how much data it will return.

Comment: Hi @DavidReed Salesforce API has a limitation when running `execute` function. So if there are more than 2000 rows in the object it won't return the other rows. I Would like to have the possibility to make a subsequent request to get more data. But so far I haven't managed do that

Answer (score 0):

Received help from the Salesforce support team

- You can only fetch a maximum of 2000 records and the remaining records can be fetched using QueryLocator
- The query result object contains up to 500 rows of data by default. If the query results exceed 500 rows, then the client application uses the queryMore() call and a server-side cursor to retrieve additional rows in 500-row chunks. You can increase the default size up to 2,000 in the QueryOptions header